# Area tag to display and hide div

Tags: jquery, html, dictionary, area

I have an area map that when i click on a specific area I would like to display a certain div that corresponds to that selection. 
I.e. if you click on square1 in the map, it will display div1. If you click on square2 it hides div1 and displays div2.
I am not able to obtain the expected result so far. I am open to suggestions if there is a better way to solve my problem.

```
<map name="FPMap0" id="FPMap0">
<area item="first" href="#" shape="polygon" coords="347, 79, 349, 201, 449,   248, 540, 204, 541, 82, 448, 34" />
<area item="second" href="#" shape="polygon" coords="560, 81, 562, 206, 660, 255, 756, 208, 758, 81, 659, 31"/>
</map>

<img width="1000" height="667" src="picture.png" usemap="#FPMap0" alt=""/>​

<div id="first">Text1</div>
<div id="second">Text2</div>

<script>
  $("map#FPMap0").click(function(ev){
  var target = $(ev.target);
  var targetId = target.attr('id');
  if(targetId == 'first') {
    $("#first").show();
  } else if(targetId=='second') {
    $("#second").show();
  }
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your `area` tags have an attribute (item) that matches the div id's, you can simply do this...

```
$('area').on('click',function() {
    $('div').hide();
    $('#' + $(this).attr('item')).show();
});
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/v29tL02n/1/)

Comment: [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rafacardosoc/s905o7b4/) As you can see the both divs are always visible... Not sure what i am doing wrong

Comment: to correct my statement, the divs are not visible when the page loads, but it is unresponsive when i click on one of the areas.

Comment: There are a few of reasons why your example JSfiddle doesn't work. 1. You are trying to load jquery over a non-secure connection(http) when jsfiddle is using a secure connection (https). The file will be blocked in this case. 2. You are missing closing quotes in your jquery URL ...

Comment: 3. Your javascript needs to be placed _after_ the elements that you are trying to trying. If the code has to be placed before the elements you must wrap your code in a [document.ready](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/) block to ensure the code isn;t executed until the DOM is loaded. Looking at your browsers console can help you find errors like this very easily - Here is a fixed example - https://jsfiddle.net/s905o7b4/5/

Comment: thank you! that worked great!! just one more question. with your approach, every time i click in the area, it will display the div associated to the click, and hide ALL other divs. in my case, i only have a subset of divs that should be hidden, i.e. "second, third, fourth", but divs "six and seven" should not be impacted. is there anyway to adapt your code for this scenario?

Comment: You could give the divs that should be hidden a class. Then replace this line `$('div').hide();` with something like this: `$('.yourClass').hide();`

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of mistakes in your code.

Try this:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('#first, #second').hide();
$("map[name=FPMap0] area").on('click', function () {
    var target = $(this).attr('item');
    if (target == 'first') {
        $('#second').hide();
        $("#first").show();
    } else if (target == 'second') {
        $('#first').hide();
        $("#second").show();
    }
});
});
```

[**JSFiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/yo0jcgxc/2/)

Comment: i tried your approach but both divs are always visible. not exactly sure what i am doing wrong. here is the code

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rafacardosoc/yo0jcgxc/)

Comment: thank you for the effort. i copied and pasted the code but the divs are both displayed at load, and nothing happens on click. do i need to specifically have two separate files (html and javascript) in order for this solution to work? i am embedding this into sharepoint, so i need the entire code into one file.

Comment: sorry @imbondbaby but it is still unresponsive. no matter what i click, i don't see the divs appear.